GroupBy a nested array of objects in TS
I have an object MealFood which contains information about a food like this:
{
 ...
 id: 1,
 main: true,
 familyId: 3,
 scheduledServings: [
  {
    ...
    time: '2024-07-09 13:00:00',
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    ...
    time: '2024-07-09 19:15:00',
    quantity: 1
  }
 ],
 ...
},
{
 ...
 id: 2,
 main: true,
 familyId: 5,
 scheduledServings: [
  {
    ...
    time: '2024-07-09 13:00:00',
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    ...
    time: '2024-07-09 19:15:00',
    quantity: 1
  }
 ],
 ...
}

I'm trying to reorganize them grouped by time -> familyId -> main so that I know that I know that on 2024-07-09 13:00:00 I have these n main foods (grouped by familyId), and other m side foods (grouped by familyId).
I'm using TypeScript 4.9.5
Since thery are objects I'm grouping by keys like this:
mainGroup = Object.keys(x).groupBy({main} => main);
Object.keys(mainGroup).forEach(main => {
 familyGroup = Object.groupBy(mainGroup[main], ({familyId}) => familyId);
 ...and so on
}

The problem is when I reach scheduledServings since it's an array I can't find a way to handle it.
I'm trying to have something like this:
[
 {
  time: '2024-07-09 13:00:00',
  family: [
   {
    familyId: 3,
    main: [
     {
      ...first main food item of with familyId 3 at 13:00
     },
     {
      ...second main food item
     },
    ]
    side: [
     {
      ...first side food item
     },
     {
      ...second side food item
     },
    ]
    ...
   }
  ],
  family: [
   {
    familyId: 5,
    main: [
     {
      ...first main food item with familyId 5 at 13:00
     },
    ]
    ...
   }
  ]
 },

 {
  time: '2024-07-09 19:15:00',
  family: [
   {
    familyId: 3,
    main: [
     {
      ...first main food item with familyId 3 at 19.15
     },
    ]
    ...
   }
  ],
 ...
]


Welcome to Stack Overflow! • This looks like a JavaScript question more than a TS question; you might want to add that tag. • Please provide a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing. It shouldn't be pseudocode (like ... all over the place) or missing declarations (x etc); the only issues we should have when looking at your code should be the ones you're asking about... otherwise it makes things much harder. • You're not just grouping existing things but making new things, right?
